# Enable-SPFeature - issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, feature

I am stucked on this error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

while tryng to enable a feature (site scoped) with `Enable-SPFeature` powershell command.
I tried to `iisreset` (with killing `w3p` processes) and I checked that the `<Class>` in the `Element.xml` is correct (with the namespace and class).

I have this issue just on prod environment, I can enable the feature on dev farm.

Comment: If you are activating through powershell and has a feature receiver, try to restart the timer service and then try again

Comment: is `iisreset` not enough?

Comment: Not if you activate through powershell, then it will not be run in the w3wp process. So, reset timer service and restart your powershell could possibly solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my solution I had a event receiver and some content type definition.
I splitted it in two different solutions (one with event receiver and other with definitions) and now it is working.

Actually I do not know why (I did not change code at all), sad story.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Enable-SPFeature xxx -Force`

Comment: with -Force I get no error but the event receiver in the feature is not working